# Standard way of handling oversize pages?

Tags: margins, geometry

In a book project, using `\geometry{letterpaper}`, there are occasional places where an oversize diagram has to be included — one much wider than a normal page — without being reduced or spread across pages. But I don't want all the other pages to be oversize, as well.

What options do I have for allowing individual pages to be oversize, on an ad hoc basis? (`\geometry` cannot be re-declared in the body of the document).

Comment: did you have a look at the `changepage` package? I've never used it seriously myself, so I don't know whether it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken in part from the TeX FAQ entry [Changing margins “on the fly”](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly):

###Horizontal adjustment:

The [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) provide a localized width adjustment of the text block with the `adjustwidth` environment. The typical usage would be

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
  %<stuff>
\end{adjustwidth}
```

if you wish the text block to extend `1cm` out of the margin on both sides of the text block. An extension to this in the form of a layout change on a per-page basis is offered by [`changelayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changelayout).

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides an analogous `adjustwidth` (and starred variant for `twoside` mode accommodation) which works in a similar way and takes similar arguments.

[`fullwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) is another package that follows in the footsteps of [`mdframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) by allowing page breaks within the margin adjustments.

From the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (section **3.18 Lists**, p 106):

> Similar to quote and quotation, the `addmargin` environment changes
> the margin. In contrast to the first two environments, with
> `addmargin` the user can set the width of the indentation. Besides
> this, this environment does not change the indentation of the first
> line nor the vertical spacing between paragraphs.

The `addmargin` and `addmargin*` environments function in the same way `memoir`'s `adjustwidth` does.

Alternatively, setting the content in a box that fits within the text boundary will make TeX happy, yet allow the content to extend beyond the text block margins. For example,

```
\begin{figure}
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[..]{...}}% Automatically centred
  \caption[..]{...}
  \label{...}
\end{figure}
```

The [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides similar means for manipulating the bounding box of its content, and interacts well with the key-value parameters of `\includegraphics` via its `export` package option.

###Vertical adjustment:

You can use `\enlargethispage{<len>}` to increase the current page by `<len>`. Or there's the [`addlines` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/addlines) that provides an analogous `\addlines` macro.

<sub>All of the above discussions are independent of the content being included.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I think I should have explained that these diagrams will generally be much wider than a normal page, rather than much longer. I will edit the original post.