# changing margins for a page with tables

Tags: tables, margins, endfloat

I have a document with a table that is rather large. I have already decreased the size of the font but it still bleeds into the right margin.  I would like to decrease the margins on that page so it uses some of the left margin as well, however, leave the margins on other pages as is.  Is there a way to do this? I am using `endfloat` so the table is on it's own page.

Comment: This question is very similar to [Standard way of handling oversize pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80409/5764), where a solution using the `adjustwidth` environment (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) should suffice. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: sounds great, let me take a look!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
\hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}.....\end{tabular}\hspace*{-1cm}
```

will make a table that sticks 1cm into the margin on each side without TeX complaining.

Comment: this is awesome!! great solution!

Comment: Why should we have it on before and after tabular section?