# An empty space between two pages in longtabular with itemize

Tags: tables, margins, itemize

You can see my problem on pictures below. I have one table (`longtable`) and there are three columns and on the 3rd column I have used tool (`itemize`) with many items. Everything runs very well but at the end of a page I still get an empty space and new `itemize` starts on the next page. I want to use all page and I would like to split items.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\section{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Predložky I}}
{\small 
\begin{longtable}{llp{5cm}}
    \toprule
    {\sffamily on}   & \textsl{[\textipa{6n}]}  & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                  \begin{itemize}
                                                    \item[-] na \textit{čom/čo}
                                                    \item[-] na povrch(u) \textit{čoho (položený, pripevnený ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] na \textit{koho/čo}, od \textit{koho/čoho}
                                                    \item[-] o \textit{čo (zraniť sa, porezať sa)}
                                                    \item[-] na palube, vnútri \textit{čoho}, v \textit{čom}
                                                    \item[-] o \textit{čom (rozprava, správa)}, k \textit{čomu (komentár ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] v \textit{čom (televízii, rádiu ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] v \textit{čom (komisii, výbore ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] \textit{za čo (minúť peniaze)}
                                                  \end{itemize}\\
    {\sffamily for}  & \textsl{[\textipa{fO:\super r}]}  & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                           \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                           \begin{itemize}  
                                                             \item[-] pre \textit{koho/čo}
                                                             \item[-] za, v mene \textit{koho (hovoriť ap.)}
                                                             \item[-] pre, za, (na)miesto \textit{koho (urobiť čo)}
                                                             \item[-] k(u), voči \textit{komu}, vo vzťahu ku \textit{komu (cítiť emócie ap.)}
                                                             \item[-] na \textit{čo (určený)}
                                                             \item[-] po \textit{(istý čas)}, počas \textit{(vymedzenie dĺžky trvania, zvyčajne neprekladáme)}
                                                             \item[-] na \textit{kedy (termín ap.)}
                                                           \end{itemize}\\  
    {\sffamily with} & \textsl{[\textipa{wID}]} & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                  \begin{itemize}
                                                    \item[-] s \textit{kým/čím (súčasne, na jednom mieste)}
                                                    \item[-] pomocou \textit{čoho, čím (nástrojom, pomôckou ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] \textit{čím (pokrytý alebo vyplnený)}
                                                  \end{itemize}\\   
    {\sffamily in}   & \textsl{[\textipa{In}]}  & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                  \begin{itemize}
                                                    \item[-] v \textit{čom}, vnútri \textit{čoho (miestne)}                                                 
                                                  \end{itemize}\\
    {\sffamily in}   & \textsl{[\textipa{tu:}]} & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                  \begin{itemize}
                                                    \item[-] do, k(u), smerom k \textit{čomu}, na \textit{čo}, za \textit{kým (smerom kam)}
                                                    \item[-] na \textit{čo (ísť - na návštevu ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] k \textit{čomu (pripevnený ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] k(u), voči \textit{komu/čomu (správať sa ap.)}
                                                  \end{itemize}\\
    {\sffamily of}   & \textsl{[\textipa{6v}]}  & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                  \begin{itemize}                                             
                                                    \item[-] \textit{koho/čoho (druhý pád alebo privlastňovanie)}
                                                    \item[-] z \textit{(o pôvode, pôsobisku)}
                                                    \item[-] z \textit{čoho (vyrobený ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] na \textit{čo/koho (myslieť, zomrieť ap.)}
                                                    \item[-] od \textit{koho (milé, podlé ap.)}
                                                  \end{itemize}\\       
    {\sffamily at}   & \textsl{[\textipa{\ae t}]}  & \setlist{nosep,topsep=0sp,label=--}
                                                     \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                                                     \begin{itemize}
                                                       \item[-] v(o), na, pri \textit{(o mieste, udalosti)}
                                                       \item[-] na \textit{(škole, univerzite - študovať ap.)}
                                                       \item[-] pri \textit{čom (stole ap.)}, za \textit{čím (písacím strojom ap.)}
                                                       \item[-] v \textit{(o vzdialenosti, uhle ap.)}, pod \textit{(určitým uhlom)}
                                                       \item[-] v, o, na \textit{(o čase, hodine)}
                                                       \item[-] (smerom) na \textit{koho/čo (ukázať ap.)}, po \textit{kom/čom (hádzať ap.)}
                                                     \end{itemize}\\
    \toprule     
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please check this question, it may be as your problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81826/changing-margins-for-a-page-with-tables

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is splitting a row in two, by trial and errors, at the best possible space. I propose some improvements. Using `tabularx` in the `\ltablex` extension will hopefully limit the number of such adjustments, by making longer lines in the last column. It is an `X` column which enters and leaves automatically an `itemize` environment, with specifications set just before entering the `tabularx` environment, so that you only have to typeset the  items. Similarly the font characteristics of the first two columns are on entering the column, and you only have to type the text.

Finally I propose to colour the IPA column rather than using `\slshape`, but it's only a suggestion, and your initial version (automated) is only commented in the preamble of the table. Also I defined a `scroman` numbering, as I  think Roman page numbering is too large for A6 paper format.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}%
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, margin=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\pagenumbering{alph}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}
\makeatletter
 \def\scroman#1{\expandafter\@scroman\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@scroman#1{{\scshape\romannumeral #1}}
\makeatother
\pagenumbering{scroman}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy
\keepXColumns
\section{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{Predložky I}}
{\small\setlist[itemize]{nosep, topsep=0sp, label=--, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, before =\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}%{@{} >{\sffamily}l>{\slshape[\tipaencoding}l<{]}>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight\itemize}X < {\enditemize}@{}}%
{@{} >{\sffamily}l>{\color{SteelBlue}[\tipaencoding}l<{]}>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight\itemize}X < {\enditemize}@{}}%
    \toprule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\endfoot
   on & 6n &
   \item na \textit{čom/čo}
   \item na povrch(u) \textit{čoho (položený, pripevnený ap.)}
   \item na \textit{koho/čo}, od \textit{koho/čoho}
   \item o \textit{čo (zraniť sa, porezať sa)}
   \item na palube, vnútri \textit{čoho}, v \textit{čom}
   \item o \textit{čom (rozprava, správa)}, k \textit{čomu (komentár ap.)}
   \item v \textit{čom (televízii, rádiu ap.)}
   \item v \textit{čom (komisii, výbore ap.)}
   \item \textit{za čo (minúť peniaze)}
    \\
 for & fO:\super r & \item pre \textit{koho/čo}
 \item za, v mene \textit{koho (hovoriť ap.)}
 \item pre, za, (na)miesto \textit{koho (urobiť čo)}
 \item k(u), voči \textit{komu}, vo vzťahu ku \textit{komu (cítiť emócie ap.)}
 \item na \textit{čo (určený)}
 \item po \textit{(istý čas)}, počas \textit{(vymedzenie dĺžky trvania, zvyčajne neprekladáme)}
 \item na \textit{kedy (termín ap.)}
    \\
 with & wID & \item s \textit{kým/čím (súčasne, na jednom mieste)}
 \item pomocou \textit{čoho, čím (nástrojom, pomôckou ap.)}%
 \item \textit{čím (pokrytý alebo vyplnený)}
    \\
 in & In &
 \item v \textit{čom}, vnútri \textit{čoho (miestne)}
 \\
 in & tu: & \item do, k(u), smerom k \textit{čomu}, na \textit{čo}, za \textit{kým (smerom kam)}
 \item na \textit{čo (ísť - na návštevu ap.)}
 \item k \textit{čomu (pripevnený ap.)}
 \item k(u), voči \textit{komu/čomu (správať sa ap.)}
    \\
 of & 6v & \item \textit{koho/čoho (druhý pád alebo privlastňovanie)}
 \item z \textit{(o pôvode, pôsobisku)}
 \item z \textit{čoho (vyrobený ap.)}
 \item na \textit{čo/koho (myslieť, zomrieť ap.)}
 \item od \textit{koho (milé, podlé ap.)}
    \\
 at & \ae t & \item v(o), na, pri \textit{(o mieste, udalosti)}
 \item na \textit{(škole, univerzite - študovať ap.)}
 \item pri \textit{čom (stole ap.)}, za \textit{čím (písacím strojom ap.)}
 \item v \textit{(o vzdialenosti, uhle ap.)}, pod \textit{(určitým uhlom)}
 \item v, o, na \textit{(o čase, hodine)}
 \item (smerom) na \textit{koho/čo (ukázať ap.)}, po \textit{kom/čom (hádzať ap.)}
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]