# Change marginpar for each page

Tags: margins, conditionals, marginpar, geometry

I want to be able to change the `marginpar` and `right` values for each page, depending if the page has notes or not. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=8cm, marginpar=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Title 1}
\lipsum[3]
\newpage

\section{Title 2}
\marginpar{%
    \lipsum[1]
}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the problem is that the first page always has a large margin. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and thus using the 2009 version of texlive, and I'm unable to update it right now, so I can't use `\newgeometry`. Is there another option I can use?

Comment: If you are willing to switch it manually, you can use the example in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34368/how-to-switch-between-two-margin-sizes

Comment: Simply download the new geometry package into the folder of you *.tex-file, then it will be used by pdfLaTeX instead of the old one in texmf-dist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Just had to `\usepackage{changepage}` and `\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5cm}` the section that I don't want to have margins. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=8cm, marginpar=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Title 1}
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5cm}
\lipsum[3]
\end{adjustwidth}
\newpage

\section{Title 2}
\marginpar{%
    \lipsum[1]
}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE working]

Comment: Probably of interest for future readers: [Standard way of handling oversize pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80422/).

Comment: From the [`chngpage` README](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngpage): "The package provides broadly similar functionality to [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage), with which it is distributed. It is, however, considered obsolete, and should not be used in new documents." So, use `changepage` instead.